# How to replace a text in a string with anchor tag in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a string like:
`var str = 'I love stackoverflow';`

I want to replace the `stackoverflow` text in with an anchor tag.

I tried with replace but its not working.
Can someone advise.

Comment: are you getting it error ? or are you saying your method doesn't work? If you get an error, share your code with the error you received.

Comment: Nothing to do with the answer, but the name of the site is Stack Overflow, two capitalized words :).

Comment: You might want to add a sample input and expected output to better illustrate your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider first removing the word `"stackoverflow"` from the string, then render it with the anchor tag:

```
const greeting = "I love stackoverflow";
const finalGreeting = greeting.replace('stackoverflow', '');

return <>
  {finalGreeting}
  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com">stackoverflow</a>
</>
```

---

Alternative solution with [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml):

```js
const HelloStackOverflow = () => {
  const greeting = "stackoverflow is my love";

  const finalGreeting = greeting.replace('stackoverflow', 
'<a href="https://stackoverflow.com">stackoverflow</a>');

  return <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: finalGreeting }}/>
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <HelloStackOverflow />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Comment: But my "stackoverflow" text is in the middle of string. Not at last.The solution provided only work if the text to be replaced is at the end of the string.

Comment: you can do this by using React's `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. Be careful when using this attribute on real life scenarios, as it can make you vulnerable to XSS attacks

Answer (score 1):

**You have following solutions to your problem.**

1. Use 3rd party library like [react-linkify](http://npmjs.com/package/react-linkify). This library is specifically build to convert urls in plain string to anchor tags.

```
<Linkify>
 See source code at https://github.com/tasti/react-linkify/.
</Linkify>
```

This will convert the link to clickable links.

2. Create a regex parser to convert links to anchor tags and then convert the string into array of strings and links and then map that array in any paragraph or where ever you're thinking of displaying this text.
3. Create a regex parser to convert links to anchor tags and then render them as `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` as suggested by **Doug**. As mentioned by Doug please be careful while using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` as it can be used for XSS attacks if values aren't properly sanitized.

If you're heavily relying on converting plain string urls to anchor tags and adding another dependency is not an issue then I will suggest you to go with 1st one.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the string like this:

```
var originalText = "I love stackoverflow";
var changedText = originalText.replace("stackoverflow", "myself");
```

Comment: i want to replace "stackoverflow" text with anchor tag by which "stackoverflow" text can as a link.

Comment: Using replace method where i can replace my "stackoverflow" text with anchor tag is not working. I am seeing [object Object] as my replaced string.